# Delay when powering LED light strip

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I made a "shop lamp" out of an [LED strip](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JQV6NNC) and [power supply](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K71VMCW).  When I plug it in there is a 1-2 second delay before the lights are powered up.  Do some transformers have a shorter delay than others?

[image: shop light]

Comment: I just don't feel your pain, I guess. Is a 2 second turn-on delay (if it's even that long) really cramping your style that much???? Beats half an hour waiting for ice-cold fluorescent bulbs to finally make it to full brightness by a few miles...

Comment: @Ecnerwal ... I feel your pain there ... I have that problem with my fluorescents in the garage in the winter time. I've been thinking of doing away with them and going to a large amount of LEDs to make up the light.

Comment: Well--I have LED bulbs throughout my house that turn on instantly.

Comment: The other issue is that when I turn on my light, I lose all my radio reception.  I'm hoping a higher-quality transceiver would address that problem as well.

Comment: It's not a transformer causing the delay. Likely a capacitor charging or an SCR waiting for voltage to stabilize before letting power out to your LED's.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger. You should post an answer. Your comment is more useful than the current answers.

Comment: I think the OP means "power supply" not specifically "transformer", and @WayfaringStranger is referring to a capacitor in the power supply (& that's probably the case).

Comment: I feel the OP's pain, the turn-on delay drives me nuts.  And the power supplies that actually have a spec on delay have imo awful specs, like "less that 3 secs".

Answer (score 1):

The more 'electronic' a power supply, the longer it takes to start up.  I had this nuisance in my pantry, where I only need light for a few seconds, so I don't want to wait another few seconds every time.  I also have a VERY high current demand from a lot of LEDs in total.

I used a sealed lead acid battery on a trickle charger, and a relays.  Battery is on common.  NO is connected to LEDs.  NC to a trickle charger.

Yeah.  I'll have to replace the battery when it goes out.  Beats waiting for a power supply to ramp up.

Long term, I think I'm going to make a service grade (100-400A) 12/24/48v DC bus for the house, with capacitors for buffering.

You might try a very simple 120vAC to 12vAC transformer (assuming thats your LED's voltage) with a rectifier and capacitor in some enclosure.  You're building electrics at that point, so test, and include fuses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are fast-start power supplies, and those which are less fast. The latter tend to be less expensive as well so paying more might get you faster response. Or might not.

I have an LED-equipped light fixture in my living room, about 300W-incandescent equivalent, which starts instantly and is dimmable. It cost me about $300 just to put those bulbs into it.

But yours is what it is, and the only way you'll improve it is to replace it -- which means finding a way to return it, or selling it off to someone else who's willing to tolerate the pause, or learning to tolerate it yourself. Wish I could tell you otherwise, but...